# How to fix django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or delete on table in Django 3.x

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-migrations

From today morning I'm getting

**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "Department_course" violates foreign key 
constraint "Department_course_Course_type_id_71e71f3c_fk_Departmen"
DETAIL:  Key (Course_type_id)=(UG) is not present in table "Department_coursetype".**

error while migrating django models. Help me to fix this problem guys.

Today morning I tried to create another two models with foreign keys of department model. From that time the issue was started.But now I deleted these two models. And still i got same error. help me to fix it

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class departments(models.Model):
    # department = models.CharField(max_length = 40, null = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, primary_key = True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="Dept_img", null = True)
    desc = models.TextField(null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class department_detail(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(departments, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    About = models.TextField(null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name


class course(models.Model):
    COURSE = (
        ('UG','UG'),
        ('PG','PG')
        )
    Department_name = models.ForeignKey(departments, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    Course_type = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=40, choices=COURSE, default = None)
    Course_name = models.CharField(null = True, max_length=80)
    Course_duration = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=30)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.Department_name.name

class carousel(models.Model):
    Department = models.ForeignKey(departments,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Carousel', null = True)
    Img_title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    Img_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.Department.name
```

Comment: Can you show your project tree?

Comment: Sorry brother, I can't understand what you mean?

Comment: Remove null=True from cource>Department_name this may help you(Same for carousel,department_detail models). `Department_name = models.ForeignKey(departments, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and then try migrating it.

Comment: Tried still not working brother

Comment: @LøvèlýÐhíñësh keep COURSE outside of the model and then try.

Comment: already tried brother not working

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug I tried to remove all the models. Then tried to migrate. But still facing same issue.

Comment: @LøvèlýÐhíñësh If you are using it just for learning things, I would suggest to reset your migrations and delete existing db(be careful). You can follow [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html). It may happen due to some constraints that are changed in new migrations, this may be causing conflicts.

Comment: Ok. But many another options or solutions?